# Work Pumping Water

Tags: calculus

A circular swimming pool has a diameter of $14$ meters, the sides are $4$ meters high, and the depth of the water is $3.5$ meters.

How much work to pump water out?

I got the integral

$$\int_0^{3.5}49 \pi \cdot y \cdot  1000 (4-y) \, dy,$$

although this is not working!

Thanks

Comment: Please explain your reasoning.  Where do $49$ and $1000$ come from?  You should say "let $y$ be measured from the base of the pool upward in meters.  We have to lift a small element of water from position $y$ to $4$ ... and so on.  You are assuming (reasonably) that no energy is recovered after the water is pumped over the edge, but should state that.

Comment: Sure. the radius is constant at 7 meters; its area 49pi*y for a given y. The weight of the water (and thus its required force) is 1000 (perhaps I should multiply this by 9.8).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming a density of $ 1000$ kilograms per cubic meter, and since the volume of the water is $\pi \cdot 7^2 \cdot 3.5$ cubic meters, the mass $m$ of the water in kilograms is $$m= 1000 \cdot \pi \cdot 49 \cdot 3.5 \approx 538.78$$

The work needed to pump the water over the pool can be obtained as $ W=mgh$, where $g=9.8$ meters per square second and $h$ is the vertical displacement of the center of mass of the water. Since the center of mass starts at half a depth of the water (that is to say, $1.75$ meters above the bottom of the pool) and has to be lifted up at $4$ meters, we get $h=2.25$ meters. So the work in Joules is given by $$ W \approx 538.78 \cdot 9.8 \cdot 2.25 \approx 11.88 \cdot 10^6$$

Comment: That's enough energy to recharge an iPhone 5 for a year!

Comment: An excellent answer!! So then how would I calculate how much work if it were to be pumped out an outlet 1m on the side?

Comment: In this case, the only change needed would be to set $h=3.25$ meters in the calculations.